# How to target specific form labels in jquery that don't have an id or class

Tags: jquery, forms, html-table

I have a form that's wrapped in a table that I have been tasked with to add a couple of new form fields using a form builder, so I don't have access to the HTML code to add id's or classes. I have added the new field, but in order to complete the show/hide on click function, which currently works for the inputs but not for the labels associated with those inputs, here is the JQuery I have(it only runs in no conflict mode):

```
       jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
           jQuery('.bsd-dynamic-toggle-section-contributor tr input[name="company"]').hide();
           jQuery('.bsd-dynamic-toggle-section-contributor tr td input[name="company"]').closest('label').hide();
           jQuery('.bsd-dynamic-toggle-section-contributor tr input[name="title"]').hide();
           jQuery('.bsd-dynamic-toggle-section-contributor tr td input[name="title"]').closest('label').hide();

         //show it when the checkbox is clicked
           jQuery('input[name="organization"]').on('click', function () {
           if (jQuery(this).prop('checked')) {
            jQuery('.bsd-dynamic-toggle-section-contributor tr input[name="company"]').show();
             jQuery('.bsd-dynamic-toggle-section-contributor tr td input[name="company"]').closest('label').show();
            jQuery('.bsd-dynamic-toggle-section-contributor tr input[name="title"]').show();
            jQuery('.bsd-dynamic-toggle-section-contributor tr td input[name="title"]').closest('label').show();
        } else {
            jQuery('.bsd-dynamic-toggle-section-contributor tr input[name="company"]').hide();
            jQuery('.bsd-dynamic-toggle-section-contributor tr td input[name="company"]').closest('label').hide();
            jQuery('.bsd-dynamic-toggle-section-contributor tr input[name="title"]').hide();
           jQuery('.bsd-dynamic-toggle-section-contributor tr td input[name="title"]').closest('label').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

The html associated is:

```
    <td><table><tbody><tr><td>
          <label class="fieldlabel"></label><input id="organization" name="organization" type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkbox"><label for="organization">&nbsp;<label class="fieldlabel" for="custom1">My donation is on behalf of an organization</label></label>
        </td></tr><tr><td>
          <label class="fieldlabel">Organization Name<br></label><input id="company" size="30" name="company" type="text" class="text" style="display: inline-block;"></td></tr><tr><td>
          <label class="fieldlabel">Title/Position<br></label><input id="title" size="30" name="title" type="text" class="text" style="display: inline-block;"></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
```

I need to target the labels for Organization Name and Title/Position. How can I get those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's `:contains` selector:

```
$("label:contains('Organization Name')")
```

More info on it in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).